# Convert a specific date into fiscal year in python

Tags: python

I am trying to classified a specific date by fiscal year in python. My code is as follows. As you can see, the date I want to convert is 5/10/2017 which is in 2017 fiscal year,

```
!pip install fiscalyear
import fiscalyear

fiscalyear.START_MONTH = 9

New_CF_Date='5/10/2017 12:00:00 AM'
blank_pos=New_CF_Date.index(' 12:00:00 AM')
New_CF_Date_0=New_CF_Date[:blank_pos]
format = "%m/%d/%Y"
New_CF_Date = datetime.datetime.strptime(New_CF_Date_0, format)

intTargetFiscalYear = fiscalyear.FiscalYear.New_CF_Date.fiscal_year

print(intTargetFiscalYear)
```

However, it keeps showing error. `AttributeError: type object 'FiscalYear' has no attribute 'New_CF_Date'` . Please help me to find the bug.

Comment: presumably you want `fiscalyear.FiscalYear(New_CF_Date).fiscal_year` ... without knowing anything about this package or what you expect ...

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, it show error ```'<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'datetime.datetime'```.

Comment: persumably it expects a datetime.datetime instead of an int for `New_CF_Date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`fiscalyear.FiscalDate()`](https://fiscalyear.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_usage.html#fiscaldate) does not take the `datetime.datetime` object as an input, so you may want to explicitly create a new `fiscalyear.FiscalDate` object using the datetime object.

```
import datetime
import fiscalyear

fiscalyear.setup_fiscal_calendar(start_month=9)

input_date='5/10/2017'
New_CF_Date = datetime.datetime.strptime(input_date, "%m/%d/%Y")
fiscal_date = fiscalyear.FiscalDate(New_CF_Date.year, New_CF_Date.month, New_CF_Date.day)
print(fiscal_date)
print(fiscal_date.fiscal_year)
```

**Output:**

```
2017-05-10
2017
```